# Do Brigitte's Armour packs return to her if the target breaks line of sight?

Tags: overwatch

Whenever I do play Brigitte I notice that some times I am able to press "E" (to apply an armour pack), however it does not apply to the target, and the cooldown get's reset. However, I recall hearing that, regardless of if line of sight is broken, the pack will still apply.

Is this due to latency or do armour packs return to Brigitte if line of sight is broken?

Answer (score 2):

That is due to latency. Armor Packs are not refunded even if the target dies before it can be healed.